# Return only first rows where array contains an element and possible leave out any elements seen earlier

Tags: postgresql

Given the following data set:

```
| page | sentence_ids |
|------|--------------|
| 1    | { 1, 2, 3 }  |
| 2    | { 1, 2 }     |
| 3    | { 3, 4 }     |
```

I'd like to do a query that would return the pages where the sentence id occurred first. Preferably with sentence_ids only occurring once in the dataset and the least amount of pages. In this case:

```
| page | sentence_ids |
|------|--------------|
| 1    | { 1, 2, 3 }  |
| 3    | { 4 }        |
```

Is this even possible? The relation is denormalized because the pages can end up in the 10 thousands, and the sentences in the 100 thousands.

Right now we load all the pages with all the sentences and filter in the code. Terribly inefficient. Hope someone can help.

Comment: So you need a custom window function that accumulates all seen elements in a set, then emits only new elements on each row, or null / the empty array if no unique elements. Then wrap the invocation of that up as a subquery in `FROM` where the outer query filters out rows with no new sentences. The custom window function is the hard bit; I think your only option at this point is to write it in C.

Comment: If you're willing to abuse the API slightly you could write a normal non-windowing function in something like PL/Python, PL/Perl, etc, declare it `VOLATILE`, and stash the set data somewhere in the interpreter namespace where it's accessible between calls. It's hacky, but this (or the C-level equivalent) is what people used to do before there were window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only practical way* is to first `unnest` the array of `sentence_ids` and then pick the combination of `page, sentence` that matches the latter to the lowest page; you can do this with a window function by partitioning on the sentence and finding a rank after ordering by page. The record with `rank=1` is the combination of interest. You then aggregate the result back into an array:

```
SELECT page, array_agg(sentence)
FROM (
  SELECT page, sentence, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sentence ORDER BY page) AS rnk
  FROM (
    SELECT page, unnest(sentence_ids) AS sentence
    FROM page_sentences) p_s
  ) p_s_r
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY page;
```

Given the size of your data this may not be a very fast solution but it is very likely to beat pulling all data and then filtering in code.

- "Practical" is here loosely defined as "anything that avoids having to follow Craig's advice". (Sorry Craig...)

Comment: Fantastic! What does the p_s and p_s_r stand for?

Comment: Sub-queries in a `FROM` clause need an alias, even if it is never used to refer to columns. p_s simply stands for the (page, sentence) combination, p_s_r adds the rank.